# Converting json to x-www-form-urlencoded python

Tags: python, json, x-www-form-urlencoded

I need to convert json files to x-www-form-urlencoded format. The code so far is looking like this. The JSON is the input i want to pass into the request but it needs to be converted first

```
import requests


url = "https://api.baselinker.com/connector.php"



params = {
    "method": "addInventoryProduct",
    "parameters":{
    "inventory_id": 7062,                    
"text_fields":{
"name":"Test-WW"},
                    "sku": "PF-0610"
}
}
headers = {
  'X-BLToken': 'X-BLTOKEN',
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}
response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=params)

print(response.text)
```

Here is output i want to achieve

```
params='method=addInventoryProduct&parameters=%7B%0A%22inventory_id%22%3A%207062%2C%0A%22text_fields%22%3A%7B%0A%22name%22%3A%22Test-WW%22%7D%2C%0A%22sku%22%3A%20%22PF-0610%22%0A%7D'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what happens according to my tests on httpbin.org:

```py
import requests

url = "https://httpbin.org/post"

params = {
    "method": "addInventoryProduct",
    "parameters": {
        "inventory_id": 7062,
        "text_fields": {
            "name": "Test-WW"
        },
        "sku": "PF-0610"
    }
}
headers = {
    'X-BLToken': 'X-BLTOKEN',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}
response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=params)

print(response.request.body)
```

You can check the sent request from the response (that is shown in the code).

Comment: When i test this on the api im trying to reach it shows this error though {"status":"ERROR","error_code":"ERROR_PARSE_JSON_PARAMETERS","error_message":""}